# select df that include value x OR value y

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, tidyverse, data-wrangling

i have a problem in my data wrangling.

I have a data.frame with different dates in one of my colums.There is also one column i am grouping but that should not be the problem.
Now, I just want to filter the df, that the new df has date x or date y included (e.g. 20-03-18 or 20-03-19). I tried function xor() but I struggle a lot and do not get any result.

```
new_df<-df%>%    
group_by(animals_id)%>% 
filter(any(day==xor("20-03-18", "20-03-19"))
```

in the end, I just want to have animals_id`s that have included date "20-03-18" or (not &) "20-03-19"

I also tried `filter(any(day==c("20-03-18", "20-03-19"))` but this just filter that include both dates

Thanks for your help!

```
df<-structure(list(animals_id = c("Hedwig", "Hedwig", "Hedwig", "Hedwig", 
"Hedwig", "Hedwig", "Heidi", "Heidi", "Heidi", 
"Heidi", "Heidi", "Heidi"), day = structure(c(17937, 
17938, 17939, 17940, 17941, 17942, 18304, 18305, 18306, 18307, 
18308, 18309), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try `new_df<-df%>%    
  group_by(animals_id)%>% 
  filter(day==as.Date("20-03-18") | day==as.Date("20-03-19"))
`

Comment: thanks, but now  new_df has just lines that include the values given in filter, but all the other dates from the animals_id are gone. I need just to watch if these dates are in the df, cause I need a specific time frame for my analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Because the data that you provide, does not have a line that contains the dates "2020-03-18" or "2020-03-19", I had to include some rows of example that contains these dates, like this:

```
df <- bind_rows(
  df,
  data.frame(
    animals_id = c("Hedwig", "Hedwig"),
    day = as.Date(c("2020-03-18", "2020-03-19"))
  )
)
```

Having that in mind, and your last comment, I understood that you want first to identify all the `animals_id` that have some value in these dates. Then, you want to filter all the data that belongs to these `animals_id`. In other words, you want to eliminate, all the data of `animals_id` that does not have some value in these dates. In my example, only the "Hedwig" id have some values in these dates, so you want to filter all the data that belongs to "Hedwig" id.

First, to indetify all the `animals_id`, I use the `%in%` operator in `filter()` from `dplyr` package. This way, `filter()` will pick every line that contains some of these dates. Then I group by animals_id and summarise it with some statistic, since I am only interested in identifying wich animals id's are in these filtered lines.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

select_animals_id <- df %>% 
  filter(day %in% as.Date(c("2020-03-18", "2020-03-19"))) %>% 
  group_by(animals_id) %>% 
  count()
```

Then, I use again the `%in%` operator in `filter()`, to search for every line in the `df` table, where the value in the `animals_id` column, are present in the `animals_id` column in the `select_animals_id` table. Because only the "Hedwig" id are present in the `select_animals_id` table, the `%in%` operator will find every line in `df` that have "Hedwig" in the `animals_id` column.

```
df <- df %>% 
  filter(animals_id %in% select_animals_id$animals_id)
```

**Resulting in this:**

```
  animals_id        day
1     Hedwig 2019-02-10
2     Hedwig 2019-02-11
3     Hedwig 2019-02-12
4     Hedwig 2019-02-13
5     Hedwig 2019-02-14
6     Hedwig 2019-02-15
7     Hedwig 2020-03-18
8     Hedwig 2020-03-19
```